# I lose connection with SQL Server after query execution

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET application, in a page I have a function wrapped to a button click, this button click inserts 200 rows into one database table.

Each time I click the button, the insert is successful, but after that, I lose the connection to the database, so my web application is freezing and I need to restart the whole server to reconnect to the database.

I tried to watch the SQL Server log from object explorer but to no avail; I watched many messages the important error cluing messages are

1. .NET Framework runtime has been stopped
2. Server broker manager has shut down

Here's my code:

```
 public static string UpdateListWithTrans(DataTable dt, DataTable DtTrans, DataTable DtTrans2, DataTable DtTrans3, int DecisionId, string status, string CurrentUser)
 {
     Connection con = new Connection();
     int UserID = GetUserId(CurrentUser);
     con.SetConn();

     try
     {
         using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("spUpdateListTransAction", con.GetConn()))
         {
             cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             con.openConn();

             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DecisionId",DecisionId);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTrans",DtTrans);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTrans2",DtTrans2);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTrans3",DtTrans3);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
             cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreationDate", TimeZone_.GetLocalDate());
             cm.Parameters.Add("@IsOk", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
             cm.Parameters["@IsOk"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

             cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
             cm.Dispose();

             con.CloseConn();
             return cm.Parameters["@IsOk"].Value.ToString();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
       con.CloseConn();
       con.DisposeConn();
       return "f";
    }
}




 public class Connection
    {
        private SqlConnection con;
        public void SetConn()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        }
        public SqlConnection GetConn()
        {
            return con;
        }
        public void DisposeConn()
        {
            con.Dispose();
        }
        public void openConn()
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();
        }
        public void CloseConn()
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit and enter your code in the question body to be more clear?

Comment: @SurajKumar I've updated with button click function

Comment: What is `Connection`? My guess is you have wrapped `SqlConnection` as some sort of shared instance. A flaw in your design. But this is just a guess as you did not share that code.

Comment: @Igor i updated with my connection class

Comment: Is your database set to [`Single-user Mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) ? That could be a problem with the default connection pooling used in ado.net.

Comment: As a side note if `Connection` is nothing more than the above code then I strongly recommend you delete it all together. Use `SqlConnection` in it's native form or create a static factory method like `public static SqlConnection CreateConnection() { return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString); }`.

Comment: Your code becomes more readable and you can use proper `using` blocks like `using(var con = Factory.CreateConnection()))` and place that right on top of the creation of the SqlCommand instance in it's using block.

Comment: ok i will try the way you mention thanks

Comment: Also note that cm.Dispose() is not needed since it's instantiated with `using`

Comment: @HardCode the problem is that after success insert, i am losing the connection , maybe dispos() is causing this problem?i will try thanks already

Answer (score 1):

First, refactor the code like this:

```
public static string UpdateListWithTrans(DataTable dt, DataTable DtTrans, DataTable DtTrans2, DataTable DtTrans3, int DecisionId, string status, string CurrentUser)
 {
     try
     {
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
         {
             using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("spUpdateListTransAction", con))
             {
                 cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DecisionId",DecisionId);
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTrans",DtTrans);
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTrans2",DtTrans2);
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtTrans3",DtTrans3);
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", GetUserId(CurrentUser));
                 cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreationDate", TimeZone_.GetLocalDate());
                 cm.Parameters.Add("@IsOk", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                 cm.Parameters["@IsOk"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                 con.openConn();
                 cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 return cm.Parameters["@IsOk"].Value.ToString();
             }
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
       return "f";
    }
}
```

Then, see if that resolves your issue. You have some mixed principals, such as explicitly calling .Dispose(), when the using statement will do that for you.

You also have some other refactoring to do. For example, don't use .AddWithValue. Instead, define your parameters this way. NOTE: I'm a VB.NET guy, but I assume the parameter DB type should also be SqlDbType.Int in C#?

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@DecisionId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DecisionId;
```

Make sure to define VarChar and NVarChar types with a size. For example:

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@Example", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32).Value = example;
```